# How to make desktop notifications from long-running shell commands?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I'm currently trying to configure sphinxsearch. The indexing takes around 7 minutes. Too long to wait so I usually start doing some other tasks before testing the results. But I would like to be notified when the indexing is finished - what are your ideas? The problem is also that the sessions are running through ssh. Ideal would be some tray notification that would watch changes on the terminal that is either minimized or shown on a different virtual desktop.

Comment: I would say a good way to achieve it would be to use a terminal which can be configured to look for output matching some regex and send a notification once a match is found. Better yet if the UI has a button somewhere on the border to toggle the feature between on, off, and automatic (meaning on as long as the window is out of focus).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple possibilities off the top of my head:

- play a music or alarmish sound file
- open a particular 'I'm done!' webpage with your browser (most browsers will just open a new tab or window if you they're already open)
- `notify-send` or `gmessage` or `xmessage`, which all do approximately the same thing: pop up an x-windows window with the message you specify.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on @pjz's answer, you could use xmessage (or any other command that will make something happen visually) like this:

```
long-running-command; xmessage "I'm Done"
```

This will pop up a small notification window when your command is done.

Answer (score 2):

I know the [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) terminal program can produce a bell when [output stops](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Silence.html#Silence) in a virtual screen... but I'm not sure if that will achieve exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't want to annoy my coworkers with beeps and when I turn to visual-bell (which is possible in most of the x terminals) I want see it because my terminal is mnimized.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Then screen probably isn't a good answer. I'll see if I can think of another.

Answer (score 2):

The current method in Linux is [link text](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/index.html).  You can interface to it from a shell script using dbus.

Comment: Thanks I found this:
http://mikelward.com/news/2009/05/gnome-terminal-notification-update.html
But it doesn't look like it's my gnome-terminal (2.28) yet.

Comment: notify-send is the shell interface - http://wagiaalla.com/blog/?p=28 http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-get-notifications-your-scripts-notify-send

Answer (score 2):

KDE's konsole has the option to notify you (bell/icon change) when a terminal session produces new output. Run the indexing in konsole, and append something like "&& echo done" to get output at the end (if there is none normally). Redirect regular output from the indexing.